# Is there a good way to dissolve a list on itself through linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, object, join

I'm searching for a way to dissolve a list with groups and users on itself. The problem is a group can be a result of only users, of other groups or even both. If a group is already in the list (and the all should be), I want to join the users. The goal should be list without subgroups and all groups should contain only users.

For example: There is a group called "All employees" consisting of subgroups with users. I need all users in the group "All employees" instead of the subgroups. I've already tried something like the code below. Is there a better way to do this? Because my code doesn't dissolve all subgroups.

```
foreach (var g in Usergroup)
{
    if (g.groups != null)
    {
        foreach (var t in g.groups)
        {
            foreach (var z in Usergroup)
            {
                if (z.Name == t.Name)
                {
                    if (g.Users != null && z.Users != null)
                    {

                        UserMapping[] tmp = new UserMapping[g.Users.Length + z.Users.Length];

                        g.Users.CopyTo(tmp, 0);
                        z.Users.CopyTo(tmp, g.Users.Length);

                        g.Users = tmp.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToArray();
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
}

internal class GroupUserClassMapping
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UserMapping[] Users { get; set; }
    public GroupsMapping[] groups { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Regards The Dentist

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the array after Usergroup class.

Comment: Maybe you want SelectMany in some way `AllUsers.SelectMany(x => x.Users)` ?

Comment: This is an excellent example of **when** to use the `Guard Clauses`.

Comment: What does "dissolve a list with groups and users on itself" mean?

Comment: And "If a group is already in the list (and the all should be), I want to join the users"? Crickey, it's too flaming hard for me to even think about.

Comment: @Enigmativity flaming ? i thought i was watching an episode of home and away :)

Comment: @TheGeneral - I was just having a Ray Meagher moment. The bloody mongrel of a question had me knickers in a knot. ;-)

Comment: It s a little bit tricky to explain. The data is provided by an api, which is not made for this kind of use. I'm trying to get a list consiting of groups without subgroups. Groups - subgroups - users should be Groups - users.

Comment: I think to have this answered, we need some example test data, and some example output

Comment: Perhaps if you could provide the relevant definitions for all the classes involved? Possibly instead of "dissolve" you mean "expand subgroups"?

Comment: Please provide the definitions of the `UserMapping` and the `GroupsMapping` objects (as you did for the `GroupsUserClassMapping` object).